# Объединение http-запросов в батч

Tags: python, requests, aiohttp, bat

Использую aiohttp и хочу объединять все входящие запросы в сервис в батч.
Например, летит 100 запросов в сервис, я их хчоу объединить в 10 батчей по 10 запросов в каждом и отдаю на дальнейшую обработку.

Kак это можно реализовать?
Вот примерный алгоритм работы, который я представляю:

**handler.py:**

```py
this = {
    'status': False,
    'data': request_data,
    'response': '',
}

request.app['requests'][request_id] = this  # записали реквест в словарь 

if len(request.app['requests']) == BATCH_SIZE:  # заполнили батч
    logging.info('Here!')
    await processing(request.app['requests'])  # обработка, которая меняет 'status' на True
else:
    while not request.app['requests'][request_id]['status']:  # пока статус False ждем
        pass
```

По идее, первый запрос падает в батч, второй тоже, третий падает в батч и запускает обработку. После обработки все три запроса отдают свои ответы.
На практике первый запрос падает в батч, печатается `Here!` и все. При отправке третьего запроса я повисаю в ожидании.

Comment: Ну так цикл `while not` не асинхронный и полностью блокирует работу aiohttp, не давая работать ни другим запросам, ни даже этому самому processing. Или добавьте какой-нибудь `await asyncio.sleep(0.5)` в теле цикла, или лучше вообще реализуйте статус через асинхронный Future или что-то типа того

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переделал через Future, как писал @andreymal и все заработало.
Вот примерный код:

**handler.py**

```py
......................
fut = asyncio.Future()
await request.app['storage'].put_to_storage(
    (fut, request_data),
)
response_data = await fut
```

Как только хранилище заполняется, выполняется его обработка:

```py
async def process_storage(self, recreate=True):
    if not self.empty():
        await processing(self.storage)
    if recreate:
        self.create_new_storage()
```

Обработка данных:

```py
async def processing(data: list):
    """Обработка батча из запросов в сервис."""
    ........
    # Кладем результат обработки данных в Future объект
    data[0].set_result(result)
```